# Does Angular 2 modify any standard prototype Objects like Array.prototype or Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am curious IF and WHAT standard Javascript objects are modified by Angular 2 and HOW it modifies them and WHATFOR.

Comment: angular doesn't modify anything, zone.js patches some async API like `setTimeout`, `promise.then` etc

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular All the source code is there. Happy hunting.

Comment: Thanks for the zone.js answer